# App crashes when calling method from activity class

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create an app that utilizes both the MediaButtonReceiver class and methods within the Activity class. In order to get the Activity class code to run I made a new instance of MainActivity and tried to run the method containing the code I wanted to run. I later discovered that this is not possible, what would be the easiest fix?

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ((AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE)).registerMediaButtonEventReceiver(new ComponentName(
            this,
            external.class));

    //external main  = new external();


}

public void variables (){ //code run when button is pressed in external.java

    final ToggleButton toggleWF = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.WiFi_toggle);
    final ToggleButton toggleBT = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.BT_toggle);
    final ToggleButton toggleNFC = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.NFC_toggle);
    NfcAdapter mNfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(getApplicationContext());
    WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

    if (toggleWF.isChecked()) {
        if (wifi.isWifiEnabled()) {
            wifi.setWifiEnabled(false);
        } else {
            wifi.setWifiEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    if (toggleBT.isChecked()) {
        BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if (mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            mBluetoothAdapter.disable();
        } else {
            mBluetoothAdapter.enable();
        }
    }

    if (toggleNFC.isChecked()){
        Class<?> NfcManagerClass;
        Method setNfcEnabled, setNfcDisabled;
        boolean Nfc = false;
        if(mNfcAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            try {
                NfcManagerClass = Class.forName(mNfcAdapter.getClass().getName());
                setNfcDisabled = NfcManagerClass.getDeclaredMethod("disable");
                setNfcDisabled.setAccessible(true);
                Nfc = (Boolean) setNfcDisabled.invoke(mNfcAdapter);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e){
            }
        }
        else {
            try {
                NfcManagerClass = Class.forName(mNfcAdapter.getClass().getName());
                setNfcEnabled = NfcManagerClass.getDeclaredMethod("enable");
                setNfcEnabled.setAccessible(true);
                Nfc = (Boolean) setNfcEnabled.invoke(mNfcAdapter);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            }

            if (Nfc == false) {
                //add code here if NFC fails to disable / enable

            }
        }
    }


}





}
```

Second class making new instance of MainActivity

```
public class external extends MediaButtonReceiver {



@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d("Button", "pressed");



    MainActivity main  = new MainActivity();

    main.variables();


}
}
```

Comment: You can not do "MainActivity main  = new MainActivity()". This is a wrong way to to something from Receiver. Read more about how to send data from receiver to activity and then update you views.

Answer (score 0):

Make your method static

```
public static void variables (){....}
```

And then simple use it

```
MainActivity.variables();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Take instance of activity like this

<pre> <code> public class external extends MediaButtonReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d("Button", "pressed");

  if(context instanceof MainActivity) {
      MainActivity main = ((MainActivity)context);
      main.variables();
    }
  }
}   </code> </pre>
```